# Cannot fetch associated values in rails application

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

I am building a light web user interface rails (4.0.0) application over an existing MySQL database as an data integration scenario. I can't fetch the associated values to the main entity **Movie**.

I generated everything by scaffolding without migrations (because the database is given). These are definitions of my two tables, which should be associated. The tables have singular name. So I use `ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false` in my config/environments/* files.

```
    CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `release_day` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `release_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `release_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` smallint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revenue` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `ageRestriction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `rating` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ratingValue` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rating_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movie` (`movie_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `rating_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
)
```

The models look as follow.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    has_many :rating
...
end
```

The problem is, when I try to perform the following query in my action in movie controller, I get just the columns for movie entity, but not the columns from rating. In other words `movie.rating` helper does not working. This is an example of that query.

```
def best_rated
    @movies = Movie.find_by_sql('SELECT m.movie_id, m.title, sum(r.ratingValue) FROM movie m LEFT JOIN rating r ON m.movie_id = r.movie_id group by m.movie_id')
  end
```

I am strugling with that for hours, does anybody have a clue, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Movie.joins(:rating).group("rating.movie_id, rating.title").sum("rating.ratingValue")
```

Comment: I tried `Movie.joins(:rating).group("rating.movie_id").sum("rating.ratingValue")` and it gives me hash of movie_id => sum(rating.ratingValue) so I am almost there. But I need also the title of the movie, how could I do that now?

Comment: when you using it with group function then it will not return fields.

Comment: I didn't figured it out with the select. But it seems that the solution for me is `Movie.joins(:rating).group("movie.title, rating.movie_id").sum("rating.ratingValue")`. It gives me the wanted result. Thank you very much HarsHarl, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Should I edit your answer? Or leave the thread like that? I am new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing this in rails way

first make rating to ratings

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ratings
end
```

in database table movies should have id field not movie_id

now if you want to access all ratings of a Movie

```
Movie.first.ratings
```

will return you all rating that have movie_id eqauls to first movie id

Comment: I know it's not the rails way and I would definitely do it the way you suggest in case I can change the database schema, which is not possible in this case.